# Convert integer to binary in python and compare the bits

Tags: python

How to convert a int `n` into binary and test each bit of the resulting binary number?

I have just got the following after a lot of googling:

```
def check_bit_positions(n, p1, p2):
    print int(str(n),2)
```

However i get an error `invalid literal for int() with base 2`. Let me know how can i get binary form of the input number and test each bit at position `p1` and `p2`

EDIT:

```
binary = '{0:b}'.format(n)
if list(binary)[p1] == list(binary)[p2]:
     print "true"
 else:
     print "false"
```

The above code works now, however how can i check for postions p1 and p2 from the end of the list?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Test if certain bits are on?

Comment: @arshajii Yes, and i want to know how to test at indexes from the start and end of the list. Please see my update.

Comment: You can back-index lists with negative indexes. `l[-1]` is the last element of `l`, `l[-2]` is the second to last etc..

Comment: @TinaS you can use negative indexes: `binary[-p1] == binary[-p2]`. And There's no need to convert a string to list, a string is iterable in python.

Comment: 'binary' is really just a string and can be used without wrapping it in a list. Try `binary[p1] == binary[p2]` without list-izing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `bin()` function:

```
>>> bin(5)
'0b101'
```

or `str.format`:

```
>>> '{0:04b}'.format(5)
'0101'
```

Comment: If you don't want the leading 0b, then use bin(s)[2:]

Comment: Thanks @RohitJain, can you even help me on how to check the list from the end, i.e position `p` from the end of a list. Also i cannot upvote due to low reputation.

Comment: @TinaS. You can use negative indices - `s[-1] == s1[-1]`. And you don't need to convert it to list. You can use indices on string too.

Comment: I have one more generic question, How can i know all the constructs of the language. As in i can see most of the answers here are using very less and optimised code, however i seem to write lengthy code due to my beginner level knowledge. Do you have any useful tips?

Comment: @TinaS You can start from official [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html). Also [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html) can be handy.

Comment: This is a low-performance solution. ints are already in binary, all you have to do is & the bits.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick function I wrote to check the nth bit of a number:

```
def check_nth_bit(num, n):
    return (num>>n)&1
```

Basically, you bitshift the number `n` times to the right, which would put the `nth` digit in the rightmost position, and by bitwise and-ing the new number with `1` (which is all 0's except for in the rightmost position), you can check if that bit is a `1` or a `0`. So, you can call this function on `num` with `p1` and `p2` and compare the results.

EDIT: This will be `p1` and `p2` from the end of the number (least-significant bit), not the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i will go with one of the above mentioned answers as it suits my current needs. However i will use your method as a helper function for future use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `format`:

```
>>> format(10, 'b')
'1010'
```

`int` is used to convert a number from any base to base 10, and you're trying to use it to convert an integer to binary which is wrong.

```
>>> int('1010', 2)
10
>>> int('20', 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-05fc7296a37e>", line 1, in <module>
    int('20', 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '20'
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashwini , i combined @Rohit and your answer and able to proceed. Could you please update me on how to test a list element at a index `p` from end.

Comment: @TinaS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111488/convert-integer-to-binary-in-python-and-compare-the-bits#comment26517026_18111488

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You have linked the same question in the comment.

Comment: @TinaS I linked my comment not question. I posted that [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111488/convert-integer-to-binary-in-python-and-compare-the-bits#comment26517026_18111488) on your question before your [comment on my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111488/convert-integer-to-binary-in-python-and-compare-the-bits/18111555?noredirect=1#comment26517064_18111555).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for your time and effort. I can accept only one answer though.

Comment: @TinaS Just for your knowledge, prefer `format` over `str.format` for this task.